# how to resize home and root partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2

#### Current partitioning

```
Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296  378849057 378281762 180.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 378849280  380325887   1476608   721M Windows recovery environment
--Free space here--
/dev/nvme0n1p5 397596672  418076671  20480000   9.8G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p6 418076672  606820351 188743680    90G Linux filesystem -> root partition
/dev/nvme0n1p7 606820352  627791871  20971520    10G Linux filesystem -> var partition
/dev/nvme0n1p8 627791872 1000214527 372422656 177.6G Linux filesystem -> home partition
```

#### Problem:

1. Not enought space for var

#### What I want to do:

- Somehow add unallocated space to partition for var

OR

- Incorporate the var partition into the root partition

#### Concerns

- If I move the root partition, GRUB will not know the new location and the OS will not boot.
- If I just copy paste var contents into the var folder using a live usb and then extend root partition, then

  - the permissions etc. or the var contents will create a problem
  - at boot time, OS will try to mount the partition at var folder and there will be a problem
  - extending root partition will cause problem in boot time

#### Help needed in

- how to update grub and other related entries if I move system's partitions
- how to extend root partition
- how to properly transfer var contents

Comment: Not all filesystems are resizable in any way. Please note the filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

First backup, second backup, third make sure you have a backup !!

To get `/var` onto the root filesystem can be done by just copy it (**not** drag and drop, use the commandline !!). I would do it with `rsync`. After the copy remove `/var` from `/etc/fstab` and reboot. Do this by booting a Linux from USB-Stick (e.g. gparted live USB-Stick).

If this is done, the extension of the root partition can be done by removing the var partition and extending the root partition. Extending should be possible with all filesystems, but with different commands. It **should** even be possible from the running system. But better as above (gparted live USB-Stick).

As far as I know, this does not interact with grub. On an UEFI system you could get rid of grub completely (systemd-boot).

It is not possible to write a complete command summary, because it depends on many things. A rough workflow (**Reminder:** any failure could make the computer unbootable and might be a data loss. Make sure you have a backup):

1. boot USB-Linux
2. mount the root partition
3. mount the var partition
4. copy the content of the var partition to the root partition in directory `var`
5. remove `/var` from the `fstab` on the root partiton
6. unmount the var partition
7. delete the var partition
8. extend the root partiton
9. extend the filesystem on the root partition
10. reboot

Comment: If using rsync or cp commands be sure to use parameter to preserve file settings, probably -a  for archive, but verify in `man rsync` or `man cp`.